# Form submitting before jQuery validation is checked on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, submit

I am using Ajax and jQuery to validate and submit the information from my form. The issue I am having is that when I click the submit button the form submits the information to the server straight away before performing the validation checks and displaying the errors?

I'm not sure what the issue is here so any input would be great!

Cheers

```
$('#submit_second').click(function() {
    //remove classes
    $('#second_step input').removeClass('error').removeClass('valid');

    var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    var phonePattern = /^\+?[0-9]{0,15}$/ ;  
    var fields = $('#second_step input[type=text]');
    var error = 0;
    fields.each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] || ( $(this).attr('id')=='email' && !emailPattern.test(value))) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            error++;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        }
        if( value.length<1 || value==field_values[$(this).attr('id')] || ( $(this).attr('id')=='phone' && !phonePattern.test(value) )  ) {
            $(this).addClass('error');
            $(this).effect("shake", { times:3 }, 50);

            error++;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('valid');
        }

    });

    if(!error) {
        //update progress bar
        $('#progress_text').html('66% Complete');
        $('#progress').css('width','226px');

        //slide steps
        $('#second_step').slideUp();
        $('#fourth_step').slideDown();     
    } else return false;
});

$('#submit_second').click(function(){

    url =$("input#url").val();
    yourname =$("input#yourname").val();
    email =$("input#email").val();
    phone =$("input#phone").val();

    //send information to server
    var dataString = 'url='+ url + '&yourname=' + yourname + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;  

    alert (dataString);

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "#",  
        data: "url="+url+"&yourname="+yourname+"&email="+email+'&phone=' + phone,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {  
            console.log("form submitted");
            alert("success");
        }
    });  
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form_to_validate').submit(function() {
    // .. stuff
});
```

Comment: I tried this but the form has multiple sections loaded dynamicaly using jquery after each section has been submitted so it dosnt work correctly as there are 2 sections each with a submit button, the first section works fine but as im trying to validate and submit the data to the server at the same time at the second stage it seems to submit the data before it performs the validation checks with the way i have my code structured?

Comment: Show us HTML in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is something like this:

```
$('#submit_second').submit(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Check out the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Dont think this will work? I dont want to prevent the form from submitting, just to happen after the validation has been checked first!

If i was to move all of the code into the one function do you think this would help to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes. You can call preventDefault just in case the validation fails, and otherwise the form will submited correctly.

Comment: I solved the problem in the end cheers! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413111/problems-with-jquery-form-validation-and-ajax-submit/11413385#11413385